# How to tell if an image was not loaded in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, logic, async.js

Currently I have this in my component

```
<img *ngIf="(showImage$ | async)" [alt]="image.alt [title]="image.title" [src]="image.src" (load)="imageHasBeenLoaded($event)" />
```

and the I do some actions in the imageHasBeenLoaded() function... but how do I handle cases where it fails? eg. if the image request returns a 404?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use (error) that way to set default image in case of 404, you can set a default pic from asset or from [placeholder](https://placeholder.com/)

```
<img [src]="slide.img" (error)="slide.img='./assets/img/default.jpg'">
```

Comment: Thx.. have been searching for the other methods like (load) but found nothing in the angular docs.. do you know where I can find some references?

Comment: load is use to know when the img is completely loaded, it will be useful to show a loading spinner till the img is loaded but i don't think that you can handle fails inside

Answer (score 0):

If you get 404. I'm pretty sure you should have had mistake in path or the name of the file. Or you didn't put them in the path that you indicated. like ./assets/img/default.jpg.

My code from my project looks like.

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let respo of work.Used" fxFlexAlign="auto" style="background:#E0E0E0; height:40px; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
    <img style="height: 40px; margin:auto;" src={{respo}} alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  </mat-card>
```

I give sources for each image through json file that finally gets to this part of the code and ends up at **src={{respo}}**. I think you should be using {{}} too. And if you get error it should mean that you made mistake spelling. be aware the path and name are **case sensitive**.

Comment: obviously the file is missing ;) but files can be removed without the database being updated so there is not an angular code error here ;) .. so why do you thing I should use {{}}? It's just another way to bind stuff?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. To be honest the only reason I suggested {{}} is because it worked for me. :D

Comment: hehe.. well then I might enlighten you on this topic. {{}} can only be used for strings.. so if you have a boolean then you must use the property binding [].. personally I find the property binding easier to read ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind `imageHasBeenLoaded()` method to  `error` event which is triggered if an error occurs while loading an external file (e.g. a document or an image).

```
(error)="imageHasBeenLoaded($event)"
```

```
<img *ngIf="(showImage$ | async)" [alt]="image.alt [title]="image.title" [src]="image.src" (error)="imageHasBeenLoaded($event)" />
```